# How to use event.target.matches to match div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .dropdown-content a{
                display: block;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a>1</a>
            <a>2</a>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onclick = function(event){
                if(!event.target.matches('.dropdown-content')){
                    alert("foo");
                }   
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make `alert(foo);` execute only when we are NOT clicking on anything inside of the `div` tag in the body. Unfortunately, it executes no matter where I click. Why?

Comment: Tried your logic (in Chrome) on a random site (changing the selector string)... and that seems to work as intended. Could it be a css issue of your `div.dropdown-content` that messes it up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
window.onclick = function(event){
 if (document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].contains(event.target)){
    // inside
  } else{
    // outside
    alert('foo');
  }
};
```

```css
.dropdown-content a{
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
</div>
```

Get your element and use [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to check whether click is in or outside. If outside then alert.

`matches` is not working because you are clicking in `a` tag which is not having `.dropdown-content` tag. So everytime value comes false. And it `alert('foo')`

Comment: Works only with first element of class - if you want to target only one occurence, better pick it by id: `if (document.getElementById('myElement').contains(event.target))`, if more, a loop would be needed I guess

Answer (score 1):

As i seen you have to add content to de div.conta, i made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/19/)
And work with the dom, className( imade right, but can use any):

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
abc
            <a class="name">1</a>
            <a>2</a>
        </div>

window.onclick = function(event){
console.log(event.target.className);


                if(event.target.className!=='dropdown-content'){
                    console.log("foo");
                }   
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$(event.target).closest('.dropdown-content').length
```

See the following JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4nb691a0/

Answer (score -1):

Because your if statement returns `false` and with ! operator returns `true`. It happens because when you clicked inside the div your actual target is `<a>` element which does not have class `.dropdown-content`.

When click outside the div it also does not have class `.dropdown-content`. So your statement always returns `false` but with ! operator it becomes `true`.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .dropdown-content a{
                display: block;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a class="link">1</a>
            <a class="link">2</a>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onclick = function(event){
                if(!event.target.matches('.link')){
                    alert("foo");
                }   
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```